# Gitlab Kubernetes Agent not working after gitlab update

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, continuous-integration

I configured the GitLab Kubernetes Agent one week ago following the GitLab instructions.

I used helm for the setup on Kubernetes Cluster, just copying and paste

Everything was working as expected before GitLab made an upgdate.

After GitLab update I got this error from the agent running on kubernetes cluster

```
{"level":"warn","time":"2023-06-06T10:07:54.918Z","msg":"GetConfiguration failed","error":"rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: failed to WebSocket dial: failed to send handshake request: Get \\\"https://kas.gitlab.com\\\": remote error: tls: handshake failure\""}
```

This is the environment:

Kubernetes version v1.27.2 running on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
1 control-plane node plus two workers
helm version v3.12.0
agent version v16.1.2

I tried reinstalling everything but same error.

Thanks for your support.